# Not able to debug on docker container with PyCharm 5

Tags: python, django, docker, pycharm

I'm trying to debug a Django app with PyChar that I have in a Docker container. Originally I only had docker-engine and docker-compose installed, but looking at this post:

https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/configuring-remote-interpreters-via-docker.html

So I've proceeded to install docker-machine, I can see it working. But when creating the remote virtualenv in Python interpreter settings page, I see no machines in the dropdown.

I've specified my docker-machine executable to be at /usr/local/bin, that's where it is (by the way, Linux Mint 17 here).

Any idea what I'm missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: I've recently upgraded to pycharm 5 and got the same issue. No docker machines in dropdown. As pycharm 5 was very recently released, this may be some kind of bug. Not sure about that. By now, I'd suggest you to run and debug apps inside docker through ssh.

Comment: @FábioGibson Fabio, I've already tried to set up a ssh server and I can find the intepreter, but I cannot debug...whenever I try to debug, PyCharm complaints it cannot find the sources in the docker instance. That makes sense since I've never specified any mapping. Do you have a working example on how to debug on docker through ssh with Pycharm? I'd really love to see it, if you don't mind, you would be a life saver!

Comment: Yes I have it working. Since you can find your remote interpreter your docker ssh seems to be all set. Now, you have to create a new run/debug config in pycharm. Set working dir as the remote source path. (your app path in the docker container. ex: /src). Add a path mapping from your host path to your remote path (the same you set as working dir).

Comment: Hello @FábioGibson, can you tell me where do I set the working dir to be the remote source path, and where do you do the mapping? Some screenshot would be awesome, thanks!

Comment: In Pycharm, open Edit Configurations from Run menu. Add a new run configuration, as the following [link](http://postimg.org/image/r7jbnmv01/)